# Python dataframe - how to modify value based on next column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe like this:
[image]

I would like to achieve something like this:
[image]

How to add minus do the number where next column value is different from second column in the same row? In the column after T2 we have W but in second columns is N in such situation I need minus before the number.

I've searched a lot of documentation and shift option seems to be useful, but no names of columns causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend, renaming your NaN-columns such that they have unique names in oder not to mix them up (sth like NaN_0, NaN_1, NaN_2, ...).

You could try sth like:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if i < 2:
        continue
    if 'NaN' is in col:
        continue
    else:
        mask = df.iloc[:, 1] != df.iloc[:, (i+1)]
        df.loc[mask, col] = df[col]* (-1)
```

I'm pretty new to pandas/python too, so it's highly probable there exists a more elegant/faster solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It's working but 'if 'Nan' in col: ' is proper - without is

Answer (score 1):

You can use iloc in python.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df.iloc[i,1] != df.iloc[i,5]):
        df.iloc[i,4] = df.iloc[i,4]*(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, if in a row value of 2nd column(i.e. index=1) and value of last column are different then negate the value in the column 'T2\n' else keep the same value. Correct me if I'm wrong about the question.

If df is your dataframe, then try

`df['T2\n']=df.apply(lambda x:-1*x['T2\n'] if x.iloc[1]!=x.iloc[-1] else x['T2\n'],axis=1)`

NOTE: Explain your question in a better way when you post a question next time